# Inter server connectivity getting lost after applying Cisco switch configuration

Tags: linux, networking, switch

I have 2 Redhat servers in cluster. The `eth0/eth2` ports on both servers are in `bond0`(which is assigned IP). The `eth0` and `eth2` from `server1` are physically connected to `giE0/3` on `switch1` and `2` respectively. Similarly `eth0` and `eth2` from `server2` are physically connected to `giE0/15` on `switch1` and `2` respectively. I have applied the below configuration for the ports `giE0/15`, `giE0/3`  on both switches:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 description @M@ "EIR1 eth0"
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1101
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!


interface GigabitEthernet0/15
 description @M@ "EIR2 eth0"
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1101
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
```

But after applying this the ports `giE0/3` and `giE0/15` on the switches are not coming up, and as a result my inter server connectivity is failing which is in turn not allowing the cluster to work properly.

Can somebody let me know what exactly I'm doing wrong and how to debug this.

Below is the complete configuration from switch1:

```
!
version 15.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname L-BR-SP-SPO-VVJ-SMS-1A05
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone GMT -3 0
system mtu routing 1500
no ip source-route
ip routing
no ip gratuitous-arps
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
ip domain-name backbone.vivo.com.br
vtp domain SP-SPO-VVJ
vtp mode transparent
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
spanning-tree mst configuration
 name SP-SPO-VVJ
 revision 1
 instance 1 vlan 300-499
 instance 2 vlan 2-9, 100-199
 instance 3 vlan 500-999
 instance 4 vlan 10-99, 200-299
!

!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
vlan 11
 name signalware_1
!
vlan 12
 name signalware_2
!
vlan 13
 name cluster
!
vlan 1000
 name PORTAS_DESATIVADAS
!
vlan 1101
 name OaM-EIR
!
vlan 1102
 name SIG-EIR
!
vlan 1103
 name DIAMETER-EIR
!
vlan 1111
 name InterConnect-Internal-EIR
!
ip tcp timestamp
ip tcp synwait-time 10
!
track 1 interface GigabitEthernet0/5 line-protocol
!
track 2 interface GigabitEthernet0/4 line-protocol
!
track 3 interface GigabitEthernet0/6 line-protocol
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Port-channel1
 description @MT@ L-BR-SP-SPO-VVJ-SMS-1A06 (Po1)
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1111
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101-1103,1111
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface FastEthernet0
 no ip address
 no ip route-cache
 shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description @M@ "EIR1 SIG eth4"
 switchport access vlan 1102
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description @M@ "EIR2 SIG eth4"
 switchport access vlan 1102
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 description @M@ "EIR1 eth0"
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1101
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/4
 description @M@ SIG_BB Vivo SW1-87/
 no switchport
 ip address 10.105.18.209 255.255.255.248
 standby 230 ip 10.105.18.211
 standby 230 priority 110
 standby 230 preempt delay minimum 60
 standby 230 authentication hsrp@321
 speed 1000
 duplex full
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/5
 description @M@ OaM_BB Vivo SW1-86/
 no switchport
 ip address 10.11.16.209 255.255.255.248
 standby 231 ip 10.11.16.211
 standby 231 priority 110
 standby 231 preempt delay minimum 60
 standby 231 authentication hsrp@321
 speed 1000
 duplex full
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/6
 description @M@ DIA_BB Vivo SW1-88/
 no switchport
 ip address 10.105.18.217 255.255.255.248
 standby 232 ip 10.105.18.219
 standby 232 priority 110
 standby 232 preempt delay minimum 60
 standby 232 authentication hsrp@321
 speed 1000
 duplex full
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/7
 switchport access vlan 1101
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/8
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/9
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/11
 switchport access vlan 1101
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/12
 description @MT@ L-BR-SP-SPO-VVJ-SMS-1A06 (Gi0/12)
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1111
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101-1103,1111
 switchport mode trunk
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 channel-group 1 mode on
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/13
 description @M@ "EIR1 DIA eth5"
 switchport access vlan 1103
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/14
 description @M@ "EIR2 DIA eth5"
 switchport access vlan 1103
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/15
 description @M@ "EIR2 eth0"
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1101
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/16
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/17
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/18
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/19
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/20
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/21
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/22
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/23
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/24
 description @MT@ L-BR-SP-SPO-VVJ-SMS-1A06 (Gi0/24)
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk native vlan 1111
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 11-13,1101-1103,1111
 switchport mode trunk
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 channel-group 1 mode on
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/2
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/4
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/2
 switchport access vlan 1000
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security maximum 3
 switchport port-security
 no logging event link-status
 shutdown
 no snmp trap link-status
 storm-control broadcast level 1.00
 storm-control multicast level 1.00
 storm-control action shutdown
 no cdp enable
 spanning-tree portfast
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
 spanning-tree guard root
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan1101
 description @M@ "OaM-EIR"
 ip address 10.11.16.204 255.255.255.240
 standby 1 ip 10.11.16.206
 standby 1 priority 110
 standby 1 preempt delay minimum 60
 standby 1 authentication hsrp@321
 standby 1 track 1 decrement 20
!
interface Vlan1102
 description @M@ "SIG-EIR"
 ip address 10.105.18.188 255.255.255.240
 standby 2 ip 10.105.18.190
 standby 2 priority 110
 standby 2 preempt delay minimum 60
 standby 2 authentication hsrp@321
 standby 2 track 2 decrement 20
!
interface Vlan1103
 description @M@ "DIAMETER-EIR"
 ip address 10.105.18.204 255.255.255.240
 standby 3 ip 10.105.18.206
 standby 3 priority 110
 standby 3 preempt delay minimum 60
 standby 3 authentication hsrp@321
 standby 3 track 3 decrement 20
!
interface Vlan1111
 description @M@ "InterConnect-Internal-EIR"
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.240
!
ip default-gateway 10.11.16.214
no ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/5 10.11.16.214
ip route 10.105.0.0 255.255.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/4 10.105.18.214
ip route 10.173.0.0 255.255.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/4 10.105.18.214
ip route 10.173.71.65 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/6 10.105.18.222
ip route 10.173.71.66 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/6 10.105.18.222
ip route 10.173.71.81 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/6 10.105.18.222
ip route 10.173.71.82 255.255.255.255 GigabitEthernet0/6 10.105.18.222
!
logging history size 100
logging trap debugging
logging facility local6
logging source-interface GigabitEthernet0/5
logging host 172.27.79.143
logging host 172.27.255.22
!
snmp-server community V1v0S4n6 RO 92
snmp-server trap-source GigabitEthernet0/5
snmp-server location BACKBONE_IP_SPO_1
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
snmp-server enable traps tty
snmp-server enable traps ospf state-change
snmp-server enable traps ospf errors
snmp-server enable traps ospf retransmit
snmp-server enable traps ospf lsa
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change nssa-trans-change
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change shamlink interface
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change shamlink neighbor
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific errors
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific retransmit
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific lsa
snmp-server enable traps config-copy
snmp-server enable traps config
snmp-server enable traps fru-ctrl
snmp-server enable traps entity
snmp-server enable traps hsrp
snmp-server enable traps ipmulticast
snmp-server enable traps pim neighbor-change rp-mapping-change invalid-pim-message
snmp-server enable traps cpu threshold
snmp-server enable traps bridge newroot topologychange
snmp-server enable traps stpx inconsistency root-inconsistency loop-inconsistency
snmp-server enable traps syslog
snmp-server enable traps vtp
snmp-server enable traps vlancreate
snmp-server enable traps vlandelete
snmp-server enable traps flash insertion removal
snmp-server enable traps port-security
snmp-server enable traps envmon fan shutdown supply temperature status
snmp-server enable traps vlan-membership
snmp-server host 172.27.255.22 version 2c V1v0S4n6 
snmp-server host 172.27.79.143 version 2c V1v0S4n6 
snmp ifmib ifindex persist
!
banner exec ^CCCC
****** Backbone Multiservico  *******

Switch   -  L-BR-SP-SPO-VVJ-SMS-1A05
Regional -  Sao Paulo
Site     -  Jaguare


*************************************
^C
banner login ^CCCC

            ****** VIVO - ACESSO RESTRITO - ******

Acessos Monitorados. Proibido o acesso de pessoas nao autorizadas.
Violacoes sao passiveis de punicao conforme politica interna da Empresa.

            ****** VIVO - ACESSO RESTRITO - ******
^C
!
line con 0
line vty 5 15
!
ntp authentication-key 1 md5 0208104B2B242D087C6E5A4B54 7
ntp authenticate
ntp trusted-key 1
ntp access-group peer 13
ntp access-group serve-only 14
ntp server 10.11.16.214 key 1 prefer source GigabitEthernet0/5
ntp server 10.105.18.214 key 1 source GigabitEthernet0/4
end
```

All other ports and vlans on switches are showing up status.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the commands to bind the Cisco ports into the port channel.  On Gi 0/3 and 0/15 add this:

channel-group 2 mode **on**

This will create a new interface, Po2 which you can assign an IP address.  I changed the command to statically create the ether-channel, since you're not using LACP.

Comment: I don't have LACP enabled on my switches as seen from the configuration already. Can you please elaborate how this is related to the issue, why do we need to bind the `gie0/3` `gie0/15` ports to port channel. If so, can't we add them to the already existing port channel 1. Sorry if I'm asking too many questions at a time, and that too if they are basic. I've a very basic knowledge of switch configurations, and have just started working on the advanced parts

Comment: When you bond the two links together on your server, you create (in Cisco-speak) an etherchannel.  You need to tell the switch to also bond the two ports together.   If you're not using LACP you can just manually bond them by typing channel-group 2 mode *on*  just like you've done on gi 0/12.  I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Ron- thanks , had a much better understanding now. One more query, do I really need to assign a IP to portchannel2 interface that will be created?...coz interfaces 3 and 15 are already under vlan 1101, which has a ip defined...can we not use the same configuration in PO2 as defined in PO1....?

Comment: Also one more concern. The Ethernet(0,2) ports involved in bonding on each server is not terminating on the same switch. i.e for server1 eth0 is terminating on sw1(0/3) and eth2 terminating on sw2(0/3). How to apply port-channel in this case ?

Comment: @Siddharth I think I need a diagram, because I'm not sure I understand your entire setup.  can you sketch something out for me?

Comment: Well not sure if I can sketch it here. I do have a network diagram. Can i share it with you on skype or if you can share a mail id ?

Comment: I sent the diagram in email, Ron